# Why does this regex fails in Python and is successful on regex101?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the follwing Python code

```
import re

regex = r"SRC=(?P<src_ip>[\d\.]*).*?PROTO=(?P<proto>\w*).*?(SPT=(?P<src_port>\d*).*?DPT=(?P<dst_port>\d*)|TYPE=(?P<icmp_type>\d*).*?CODE=(?P<icmp_code>\d*))"
input = "<4>Nov 25 12:00:13 ubuntu kernel: [  574.036758] iptableslogIN=enp0s3 OUT= MAC=44:85:00:ec:eb:2b:00:21:55:ef:8c:7f:08:00 SRC=10.24.136.232 DST=10.23.85.76 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=5250 PROTO=TCP SPT=56325 DPT=55 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0"
m = re.match(regex, input)
print(m.groupdict())
```

which fails with a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/scratches/scratch.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(m.groupdict())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'
```

because `input` was not matched.

The exact same regex and input is [successful on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LzsII0/1). Why?

Comment: Your regex *may* be hard to debug :/

Comment: Replace `re.match` with `re.search`. See https://ideone.com/bjl4MQ

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Wow, nice!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks a lot - this is it. I did not know about `search()` vs `match()`

Comment: You are welcome. Some people do not know http://regex101.com exists. :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: regex101 is fantastic for people like me who use regex three times a year. It is also suggested on SO when asking a regex question (I guess if the title includes the word 'regex'). Thanks again.

Comment: Then a hint: when testing at regex101.com, pay attention to the modifiers you use and whether replacing is  needed. After the fiddle works as expected, just go to *code generator* and select *Python* option. You will get some code that *might* work in Python. Always test the regexes in the target environment as you did, since even regex101.com has bugs.